# Return a double as a non scientific string

Tags: java, android, string, double, bigdecimal

I have a arithmetic operation wich result i want to display in a EditText field.

When I work with double, it returns me in some cases a scientific notation.

For Example:

5 / 10 * 0.001 = 0.0005

```
double a = 5;
double b = 10;
double c = 0.001;

double result = a / 10 * c;
Log.d("Math Test",String.valueOf(result));
```

Result:

> 5.0E-4

I tried to use BigDescimal:

```
Log.d("Math Test",String.valueOf(new BigDecimal(result)));
```

I get:

> 0.0005000000000000000104083408558608425664715468883514404296875

But I want: 0.0005

**EDIT:**
The values come from a user Input, also i could be that it is not 0.001 but 0.00001.

The Android Calculator doesn't have this problem.

Comment: A double isn't a string of any kind. The conversion to scientific notation happens when you format it for printing somehow, e.g. via the `String.valueOf(double)` call in your code. Use `DecimalFormat` to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using BigDecimal, after operating with it try using the .toPlainString() method.

Example:

BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("15286272825272726272.72728272");

//Print it
System.out.println("Plain number is: " + number.toPlainString());